# ASP.NET Core : view directory with nested folders

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I am creating an e-commerce website in ASP.NET Core. I am facing an issue with routing.

The problem is with the `Shop` folder in views. I have nested folders in `Shop`, which are `Men`, `Women`, `Kids` & `Accessories`. These subfolders have views like `Casual`, `Shirts`....

I am unable to access these views (Casual, Shirts...) - trying to do so results in a HTTP 404 not found error each time.

Project directory is:

[PROJECT DIRECTORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP1lj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be their things:

1-Check your Controller for return to view

---

2-If you didn't change the default routing, which is

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

You can access it with the that pattern

---

3-if you're sure about the two options above, check your
`href atribute` in your links

let me know if it's helped you….if it didn't, we can work on it

And this the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) for routing

Comment: Could you please share us how are you calling those route in your code or either in `controller` or `views`?

Comment: Hi
Can you provide more info about your question?
It's very ambiguous!